# Symbol lookup for the calling process?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, loading, symbols

Warm greetings to all!

So Linux has the *dlopen* / *dlsym* / *dlclose* / ... functions, but I was wondering if there is a way for my program to get a handle to some symbol of it's own running process.

Basically like dlsym, but searching for symbols in the process that called it.
Is there such a thing? Is that even possible? Bonus points: Does Windows have such a thing?

**Edit** - further clarification: Imagine I have a global variable *foo*, presumably residing in the bss or data segment of my program. The existence of *foo* is completely unknwon to the entire program at compile time. At runtime, I'd want to query if somewhere there is perhaps a global symbol called "*foo*" and if so, get it's location in memory.

I'd need to be able to build a symbol table, much like the linker does when building a shared library. I suppose this is the biggest problem.

What are my options, if I even have options?

Cheers!

Comment: `&symbol` is the handle of the symbol of your own process. For functions you can omit the '&', as function symbols used as expression are converted into a pointer anyway. Maybe you want to reword your question though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lars! I'm aware the _&_ symbol evaluates to the address of an entity. The problem is that the entity I want to address is not known at compile time - it's name gets resolved at runtime. You're right, I should probably clarify my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html:

> If *filename* is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main program.

I.e. you can `dlopen` yourself by passing `NULL` as the name.

Comment: Ah yes, maybe I should read the documentation for thoroughly. Thanks, this is what I was looking for!